# How to align columns in a grid to be independent of content?

Tags: html, css, angular, styles

I have a grid with 3 columns (`string`, `buttons`, `price`). I want set grid to be divided into equal 3 parts. Now buttons in the middle are not equal if any of the price on the right are longer than others. How to fix it?

```css
.fab-button {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table;
}

.fab-button div {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 11px;
}

.fab-button .plus {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 rgb(0, 0, 0), 0 -3px rgb(0, 0, 0), 0 3px rgb(0, 0, 0), -3px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0), 3px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0), 0 -6px rgb(0, 0, 0), 0 6px rgb(0, 0, 0), -6px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0), 6px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.fab-button .minus {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 rgb(0, 0, 0), -3px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0), 3px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0), -6px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0), 6px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group-item">
  <div class="grid-container" style="grid-template-columns: 35% auto auto;">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <h6 style="size: 10px; float:left;">{{ item.name }}</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <a class="fab-button red bg-success" style=" float:right;">
        <div class="plus"></div>
      </a>
      <a style="float:right; size: 20px; padding-right: 2mm; padding-left: 2mm;">
        <strong>{{count}}</strong>
      </a>
      <a class="fab-button red bg-success" style=" float: right;">
        <div class="minus"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <span class="text-muted" style="float:right;">
                {{ item.price }} zł
            </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: can you please add a draing of the intended layout?

Comment: @tacoshy I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your inline-styling you have:

```
grid-template-columns: 35% auto auto
```

--> so at the moment your columns are splitted by 35% | 32,5% | 32,5%

and the content in the second column is floating right. I dont know if i understand your issue but with `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto` or `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr` you have equal sized columns.

Further you can align your content inside the columns.